# What is the purpose of turning off MAMP PRO?

Tags: macos, mac, mamp

I'm using the MAMP PRO trial. It has an option to turn on or off the server, but after Googling a bit I see there's no turning on or off for a regular server set up without this kind of software. I'm wondering what's the point of turing off MAMP PRO does anything other than make it unusable, and why doesn't regular servers don't need the option?

Sorry! This may be a basic question, I've never configured a server or development environment before. I'm using MAMP PRO right now but hope I can learn all the knowledge to set up a local development environment without it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MAMP runs its own MySQL and Apache processes, if you ever wanted to run such processes standalone, they would conflict with MAMP unless you turned MAMP off or configured them to run on different ports.

Comment: Then do I need to turn off the standalone processes for MAMP Pro? How?

Comment: MAMP manages its own processes, so turning off MAMP means turning off its MySQL and Apache daemons. If you're only running one website or only running websites through MAMP that should be all the control you need.